# to get phone number programmatically in Android

Tags: android, telephonymanager, sim-card

I am using the code

```
TelephonyManager tMgr =(TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
  mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

to get the phone no programatically in android . But this is working fine only for one sim card.
If i test this code by inserting other sim card, it is giving `null`. I am trying to find the solution for this. please help me. I have also included [`READ_PHONE_STATE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_PHONE_STATE) permission in `Manifest`.

I want to uniquely identify the sim card. IS there any other way to do this. please let me know.

Comment: can u provide your solution here for getting the phone number programatically.plz can u help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think Sim serial Number is unique. You can try this.

```
TelephonyManager telemamanger = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String getSimSerialNumber = telemamanger.getSimSerialNumber();
```

Let me know if there is any issue.

Comment: Hi, I only got the solution around a month ago. Any way thanks for ur interest

Comment: Hi Prabhu, Could you mention the solution you have got for your issue?

Comment: What about multi sim mobile?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. Many SIM across the globe would return null. You should rather use IMEI number however even that can return null.

```
TelephonyManager.getDeviceId()
```

Comment: Hey , I know this is a known issue. But I need to uniquely identify the sim card.

Answer (score 1):

Look for TelephonyManager.getSubscriberId(), this will give the unique id for each SIM.

Comment: Hey, TelephonyManager.getSubscriberId() gives same id for two different sims of same network. I am using serial number of sim to uniquely identify sim

Comment: No, getSubscriberId return you unique IMSI value for GSM phone, even if you have two different sims of same network. Check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getSubscriberId%28%29

Comment: On some phones or networks only the first 6 digits of the 15-digit subscriber id is returned.

Answer (score 1):

With API Level greater than or equal to 22 : 
You can access all the SIM details using [SubscritionManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager). Use following command to list all Sim numbers(Works well for Dual Sim also):

```
List<SubscriptionInfo> list = SubscriptionManager.from(getApplicationContext()).getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
for(SubscriptionInfo s : list){
   Log.d("SIMMANAGER",s.getNumber());
}
```

Note : This only works well when the operator stored their mobile number in sim card. Else, this method returns null.