# How to get current SIM card number in Android?

Tags: android, phone-number, telephonymanager, sim-card

I want to know user mobile number in Android. I used this code but I'm not getting number.

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
        String n = tm.getLine1Number();
```

Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Is it compulsory to save number in android mobile  `settings --> about phone --> status --> myphone number`

Any idea on this?

Comment: Do you have READ_PHONE_STATE permission?

Comment: uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

Comment: @Madhavi : depend on device. so make sure you are not using any dual sim or Chinese device?

Comment: This is common issue.... some devices returns the number and some not (either they have phone app). Here is a good algo which can be useful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134398/telephonymanager-getline1number-failing/5134725#5134725

Comment: possible duplicate of [to get phone number programatically in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948446/to-get-phone-number-programatically-in-android)

Comment: @Madhavi Please see my answer, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 31):

I think sim serial Number and sim number is unique. You can try this for get sim serial number and get sim number and Don't forget to add permission in manifest file.

```
TelephonyManager telemamanger = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String getSimSerialNumber = telemamanger.getSimSerialNumber();
String getSimNumber = telemamanger.getLine1Number();
```

And add below permission into your `Androidmanifest.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Let me know if there is any issue.

Comment: i write above code but my sim number is empty. so what i want to do?

Comment: Suppose if i change the sim card with same phone number whether i get same sim serial number ?

Comment: get null value in all device

Comment: the getSimSerialNumber() function returns a string which contains provider info etc. If you want to get the pure sim serial number you have to get the last 14 numbers

Comment: sim number s not unique because this method won't return it for all devices with sim-cards

Answer (score 10):

Getting the Phone Number, IMEI, and SIM Card ID

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) 
            getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
```

For SIM card, use the getSimSerialNumber()

```
    //---get the SIM card ID---
    String simID = tm.getSimSerialNumber();
    if (simID != null)
        Toast.makeText(this, "SIM card ID: " + simID, 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Phone number of your phone, use the getLine1Number() (some device's dont return the phone number)

```
    //---get the phone number---
    String telNumber = tm.getLine1Number();
    if (telNumber != null)        
        Toast.makeText(this, "Phone number: " + telNumber, 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

IMEI number of the phone, use the getDeviceId()

```
    //---get the IMEI number---
    String IMEI = tm.getDeviceId();
    if (IMEI != null)        
        Toast.makeText(this, "IMEI number: " + IMEI, 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Permissions needed

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Does this require runtime permission? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

**Update: This answer is no longer available as Whatsapp had stopped exposing the phone number as account name, kindly disregard this answer.**

=================================================================================

Its been almost 6 months and I believe I should update this with an alternative solution you might want to consider.

As of today, you can rely on another big application Whatsapp, using AccountManager. Millions of devices have this application installed and if you can't get the phone number via TelephonyManager, you may give this a shot.

Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

Code:

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
Account[] accounts = am.getAccounts();

ArrayList<String> googleAccounts = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Account ac : accounts) {
    String acname = ac.name;
    String actype = ac.type;
    // Take your time to look at all available accounts
    System.out.println("Accounts : " + acname + ", " + actype);
}
```

Check actype for whatsapp account

```
if(actype.equals("com.whatsapp")){
    String phoneNumber = ac.name;
}
```

Of course you may not get it if user did not install Whatsapp, but its worth to try anyway.
And remember you should always ask user for confirmation.

Comment: it returns name of app not the number

Comment: Viber (not WhatsApp) add the phone number to the name field!

Answer (score 2):

You have everything right, but the problem is with `getLine1Number()` function.

> **getLine1Number()-** this method returns the phone number string for line
>   1, i.e the MSISDN for a GSM phone. Return null if it is unavailable.

this method works only for few cell phone but not all phones.

So, if you need to perform operations according to the sim(other than calling), then you should use `getSimSerialNumber()`. It is always **unique**, **valid** and it always **exists**.

Answer (score -20):

You can use the TelephonyManager to do this:

```
TelephonyManager t = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
String number = t.getLine1Number();
```

Have you used

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Please read the question description. Dont just answer by reading the title.

Comment: This is not working in my case atleast. It is giving empty string. I tested on Nexus 4 with android 4.4 and Galaxy grand with 4.2.2