# Is there a way to get the Vendor ID of charger of the Android phone?

Tags: android, android-usb

I'm thinking about an App to provide security for Android Phones. My idea is to save the vendor ID or some sort of unique ID of the USB Charger. It'll act as a paired device. Then the charger will be authorized. If the phone is charged with different charger it should trigger an SMS to some pre-loaded mobile numbers that the mobile was stolen.
Maybe it is a silly question. But I have to do this. In android is there a way to find the vendor ID of the USB charger. I don't have any method to do this. So if any know please guide me how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is any way that an Android device can get charger details. However in your context, you can think of other ways to identify mobile theft such as removal/swapping of the sim card, unkown location etc.

Comment: do we have an event to detect SIM card change? Because we Switch Off/On the device to change SIM card. @S_Madushan

Comment: You can ofcourse detect the sim card when running for the first time and save current sim card information in shared preference file. And in a device boot, get the sim card details again and compare the values. (Note : I found a good answer on how to detect sim card details here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/29097914/2603900)

Comment: @S_Madushan thanks for the reference mate. I'll try that one.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible ! There are no ways to ger charger details from an Android device.