# How to get sim slot number

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I want to get sim slot number for incoming and outgoing calls in broadcast receiver. I've tried the below code but doen't work for me

```
Log.d("TAG " , "SLOT" + intent.getExtras().getInt("com.android.phone.extra.slot"));
```

Comment: Hi, May i know how you managed to sovle the isue

Comment: @Anand, We could not fix this issue

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
     String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

or check with

```
String getSimSerialNumber = telemamanger.getSimSerialNumber();
```

Also add this permission on Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

There is no guaranteed solution to this problem because the phone number is not physically stored on all SIM-cards

Also check this answer [How to get current SIM card number in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16432458/2610010)