# Get sim number in android programmatically

Tags: android

I want to verify that user cell number is same as the sim number used in the device during registration in android application.

How do I get the sim number in my app to compare with the user entered number?

If it is impossible then any other verification process?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current SIM card number in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051023/how-to-get-current-sim-card-number-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

This code can find the sim number but only if the number is saved our phone 
directory or we can never find the sim number in any case.

```
 TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) 
 getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
 mobile number = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
```

Really it is impossible only those device which has saved their sim number 
can possible. OTP verification process is best for this , please enter your 
number and get a otp to verify.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code to get sim serial number and get sim number

```
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String getSimSerialNumber = tManager.getSimSerialNumber();
String getSimNumber = tManager.getLine1Number();

Log.v(TAG, "getSimSerialNumber : " + getSimSerialNumber +" ,getSimNumber : "+ getSimNumber);
```

Add below permission into your Androidmanifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: can i use this method to verify user cell no

Comment: its giving me null :(

Comment: You can not find the sim number and also i have used this but gives always null

Comment: Cell phone number is dependent on the SIM Card and the Network operator / Cell phone carrier.

Comment: Read More Details in this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23675998/4519859

Comment: We can not find sim number in android by codes . we can verify user number by OTP

Answer (score 0):

You can find the first sim number using this code.

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
mobileNumber = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
```

Add this `uses-permission` also in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

This code will help you but some time it does not return the exact result. Best option is to verify the number after asking the user for their mobile number.

This would help you, it has helped me.