# How to get Mobile number from SIM card in Android Programmatically using kotlin language?

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried using below piece of code but it is not giving me the number. Your information would be great help.

## Code below:

```
val subscription =SubscriptionManager.from(context).activeSubscriptionInfoList
for (subscriptionInfo in subscription)
{
   val number = subscriptionInfo.number
   Log.e("Test", " Number is  " + number)
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Correct way to get IMEI Number KOTLIN

```
try{
    val tm = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
    val IMEI = tm.getImei()
    if (IMEI != null)
        Toast.makeText(this, "IMEI number: " + IMEI,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

}catch (ex:Exception){
    Log.e("",ex.message)
}
```

Including asking for Permission

```
  if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
    } else { ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE), 2) } }
```

Don't forget AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14051023/how-to-get-current-sim-card-number-in-android) and translated to kotlin:

Getting the Phone Number, IMEI, and SIM Card ID

```
val tm = getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager

// For SIM card, use the getSimSerialNumber()    
//---get the SIM card ID---
val simID = tm.simSerialNumber
if (simID != null)
    Toast.makeText(this, "SIM card ID: " + simID,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Phone number of your phone, use the getLine1Number() (some device's dont return the phone number)

```
//---get the phone number---
val telNumber = tm.line1Number
if (telNumber != null)
    Toast.makeText(this, "Phone number: " + telNumber,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()


// IMEI number of the phone, use the getDeviceId()
//---get the IMEI number---
val IMEI = tm.deviceId
if (IMEI != null)
    Toast.makeText(this, "IMEI number: " + IMEI,
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Permissions needed:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Please note that **some devices could not return the phone number** due to its internal implementation.

Comment: I tried in 3 Samsung devices with android 5,6 and 7 versions.

Comment: Yeah, Samsung is known for change the internal apis, anyway is difficult to achieve this in particular. take a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41739519/1797950) also

Answer (score 0):

Right now you can not access these Info according to [docs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#non-resettable-device-ids):

- `getSerial()`
- `getImei()`
- `getDeviceId()`
- `getMeid()`
- `getSimSerialNumber()`
- `getSubscriberId()`

If your app targets Android 10 or higher, a `SecurityException` occurs.

If your app targets Android 9 (API level 28) or lower, the method returns `null` or placeholder data if the app has the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission. Otherwise, a `SecurityException` occurs.