# Get phone number of the current phone

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the phone number of the current phone, and I've used this code (I already have permissions in the manifest):

```
TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;    
mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);     

String phoneNumber = mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
```

I tried this code in the android emulator and it works fine and gives me a number (I guess it's the emulator's phone number),

However when I tried this code on my phone(galaxy s2) it returned an empty string.

Thanks

Comment: try this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6420783/794088

Comment: -1 This question has been asked about a million times here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getLine1Number()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number%28%29) is not guaranteed to return a phone number. It only works if the SIM card in your device has the number stored on it.

You can check if it does by going to `Settings -> About -> Status` and seeing if the phone number is available there. If it isn't, then your carrier doesn't keep the number on the SIM card

Comment: is there another way to get the phone number when the number doesnt stored in the sim card?

Comment: @AdirRahamim Short of asking the user to input it, no.

Comment: hi, so how whatsapp android get my phone number?

Comment: @AdirRahamim They ask you to enter it the first time you setup.

Comment: thanks alot,i really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Source : [Reading device phone number throws NULLPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534534/android-reading-device-phone-number-throws-nullpointerexception)

In India some operator, this phone number returned is which is stored on the SIM card's MSISDN, which isn't filled by some operators. So it return empty try it with other SIM.

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number%28%29) for `getLine1Number()` says this method will return null if the number is "unavailable", but it does not say when the number might be unavailable.

Comment: is there another way to get the phone number when the number doesnt stored in the sim card?

Comment: @AdirRahamim You can get Number which is stored only. You can ask user to input the number