# Android - Getting SImcard Number ? Will it work for all the Network Providers?

Tags: android, networking, device, telephonymanager, sim-card

I am planning to get the Simcard number inserted in the android devices. So for that , i am trying this coding snippet,

TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
String phoneNumber=  tm.getSimcardNumber();

my question is , Whether I can get Simcard Number of all the Network Providers or not. Please suggest me . Looking forward to the reply.

Regards
Anand

Comment: do you have an option that user enter his phone number himself, like viber did? because that might be better

Comment: It might not be working on some network operators as this information is embedded on sim card. So better look for some user input option.

Comment: No no..I need to create a service if the user has changed the particular SImcard i need to intimate to others. So i asked..

Comment: you might try get sim serial number, here's link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948446/to-get-phone-number-programatically-in-android?rq=1   because thats suppose to be unique

Comment: 'getSimcardNumber()' is not in TelephonyManager. Where did you get?

Comment: You might wish to explain what you think a "simcard number" is. Do you mean the IMSI? The IMEI? After all, there is no `getSimcardNumber()` on `TelephonyManager`, so we are having to guess what you mean by "simcard number".

Comment: getSimSerialNumber()
Returns the serial number of the SIM, if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

some of mobile network providers store sim number in their sim cards
but lot of them dont did this because of network flexibility like MTN

you cant trust to functions like this . in same situation i used recieved text messages to get phone number